# Does "push the resolution to a very high level" sound natural?

Tags: grammaticality, american-english

Does the sentence below sound natural?

> The megapixel war in the camera industry has pushed the resolution of image sensor to a very high level.

p.s. I write this sentence in an academic paper.

Comment: How many sensors are you talking about?  I'm afraid this question is flirting with the 'proofreading request' rule. Can you say what your specific concern is with this sentence?

Comment: I mean image sensor in any camera. For example 10 years ago, the resolution of image sensor in a typical dslr camera was  a few megapixels. Now it is tens of megapixels.

Comment: And what I'm concern is the use of 'push' in this sentence.

Comment: "Sensor" should be "sensors".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds perfectly natural and appropriate, at least as far as technical writing sounds natural, with the caveat that sensor should be plural. I'm a native AmE speaker with a technical education and career history, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

You may replace "pushed" by **boosted** (*To boost means to encourage, assist, or improve; to increase or raise*).

> Example: In many African countries, agricultural production was *boosted* by favourable weather conditions.

Comment: Generally, boosted implies a cooperative or favorable influence, as in your example. Pushed implies a less cooperative  process, and is more appropriate in describing the effects of competition.